# modal form validation after using select2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, jquery-select2-4

I am using partialview in modal form. In this form there is a select2 option list which working fine. But when press submit button, required fields as per model are not validating i.e. not showing error.

I have used lots option from internet, but failed to get the desired result.

When we remove the select2 field from partialview, it's working fine.

**Cust_Mast.cs** Model

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IDESK.Models.Customer
{
    public class Cust_Master
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "CUST_CODE")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Customer Code")]
        public int  CUST_CODE { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "CUST_NAME")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Customer Name")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string CUST_NAME { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "CUST_REGN")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Customer Regn")]
        [MaxLength(20)] 
        public string CUST_REGN { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "SALES_ORG")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Customer Sales Orgn.")]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string  SALES_ORG { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "CUST_GROUP")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Customer Customer Group")]
        [MaxLength(20)] 
        public string CUST_GROUP { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "INCO_TERMs")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Inco Term")]
        [MaxLength(5)]
        public string INCO_TERMS { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "BILL_CURRENCY")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Bill Currency")]
        [MaxLength(5)]
        public string BILL_CURCY { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Is Pallet?")]
        public bool IsPallet { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<IDESK.Models.Customer.Cust_Master>
<!DOCTYPE html>
@*<div id="notification"></div>*@

<div id="modal-placeholder"></div>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h4 style="color:indigo">Customer Master Index</h4>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="UploadFileData">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="ajax-modal" data-bs-target="#customer_model"
                    data-url="@Url.Action("Create",new {Model })">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                Create
            </button>
            <input type="submit" id="thisbutton" value="Upload data" class="btn btn-primary" />
            @{
                <!--accept="csv/CSV"-->
                if (TempData["upload"] == "OK")
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Save List", "SaveList", new { action = "SaveList" }, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary small" })
                }
            }
            <div>
                <input type="file" id="fileName" name="fileName" accept="Text/CSV" title="Select a file" style="margin-top:5px" />
            </div>
        </form>

        @{
            if (TempData["Message"] != null)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Raw(TempData["Alert"])
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }

        @await Html.PartialAsync("_tblCustomer", Model)



    </div>
</body>
@section Scripts {
    @*<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

 

        $('body').on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
            $(this).find('select').each(function () {
                var dropdownParent = $(document.body);
                
                if ($(this).parents('.modal.in:first').length !== 0)
                    dropdownParent = $(this).parents('.modal.in:first');
                $(this).select2({
                    dropdownParent: $('#customer_model'), //dropdownParent
                    
                });
                //$("select").on("select2:close", function (e) { //---this for all
                $("#ddlCustGroup").on("select2:close", function (e) { //---this for specific.
                    //$(this).valid();
                    $(this).trigger('blur');
                });

                $('#customer_model').validate({
                    ignore: null
                });

                $select.rules('add', 'required');

            });
        });


        @* $(document).ready(function () {

            $('button').click(function () {
                // $(this).valid();
                //if ($(this).valid())

                $('.modal-header').load('@Url.Action("ShowMsg")');
                //  $('.modal-title').append("<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'><button type='button' class='close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>Success</div>")
                //else
                //   $('.modal-body').append("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'><button type='button' class='close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>Failed</div>")
            })

        });*@

        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myForm');
    </script>
}
```

**_Customer.cshtml** --partialview.

```
@model IDESK.Models.Customer.Cust_Master;
@{
    Layout = null;
    
}

<link href="~/lib/select2/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/select2/js/select2.js"></script>

<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script> <!--For modal form-->
@*https://softdevpractice.com/blog/asp-net-core-mvc-ajax-modals/*@
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div id="modal-placeholder"></div>
<div class="modal fade" id="customer_model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="customer_modelLabel"
     data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" id="movableDialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: white; color: black; width: 600px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #337ab7; color: white; cursor: move">
                @{
                    if (ViewBag.action == "Edit")
                    { <h6 class="modal-title text-center" id="customer_modelLabel">Update Raw Material</h6> }
                    else if (ViewBag.action == "Delete")
                    { <h6 class="modal-title" id="customer_modelLabel" style="color:darkorange">Shown Material will be deleted.<br />Please confirm?</h6> }
                    else
                    { <h6 class="modal-title" id="customer_modelLabel" style="text-align:center;">Create Raw Material</h6> }
                }
                @*<h4 class="modal-title" id="rawmaterialLabel" style="text-align:center">Create Raw Material</h4>*@
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" style="color:darkred">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form asp-action="Create" id="myForm">
                    <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <label asp-for="CUST_CODE" class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
                                <input asp-for="CUST_CODE" readonly class="form-control col-md-4" style="color:darkgoldenrod;" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="CUST_CODE" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-inline" style="margin-top:5px">
                                <label asp-for="CUST_NAME" class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
                                <input asp-for="CUST_NAME" class="form-control col-md-8" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="CUST_NAME" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-inline" style="margin-top:5px">
                                <label asp-for="CUST_GROUP" class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
                                <select asp-for="CUST_GROUP" class="form-control select2-results  col-md-6" id="ddlCustGroup" name="CUST_GROUP" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.CustGroup, "Value", "Text"))">
                                    <option value="">---Select Customer Group---</option>
                                </select>
                                <input type="hidden" name="CUST_GROUP" value="@Model.CUST_GROUP" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="CUST_GROUP" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-inline" style="margin-top:5px">
                                <label asp-for="CUST_REGN" class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
                                <input asp-for="CUST_REGN" class="form-control col-md-6" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="CUST_REGN" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @{
                        if (ViewBag.action == "Edit")
                        {
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @*<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />*@
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Edit" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.CUST_CODE" />
                                    @*<span><a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary">Back to List</a> </span>*@
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        else if (ViewBag.action == "Delete")
                        {
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @*<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />*@
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Delete" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.CUST_CODE" />
                                    @*<span><a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary">Back to List</a> </span>*@
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @*<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />*@
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Create" />
                                    @*<span><a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary">Back to List</a> </span>*@
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                @{
                    if (ViewBag.action == "Delete")
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-save="modal">Delete</button>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-save="modal">Save</button>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#customer_model').bind("viewtransfer", function () {

        $('#myForm').removeData('validator');

        $('#myForm').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');

        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myForm');

    });


    //$("#myForm").removeData("validator")
    //    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation")
    //    .off("submit.validate click.validate focusin.validate focusout.validate keyup.validate invalid-form.validate");
    //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#myForm");
   
    </script>
```

**---Site.js----**

```
//const { Alert } = require("./lib/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.esm.js");

// Write your JavaScript code.

$(function () {
   
    var placeholderElement = $('#modal-placeholder');
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: ""
    });
    //$('button[data-bs-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
    $(document).on('click', 'button[data-bs-toggle="ajax-modal"]', function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            placeholderElement.html(data);
            placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
            
        });
    });

    placeholderElement.on('click', '[data-bs-save="modal"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var dataToSend = form.serialize();
        
        $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {
            var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);
            placeholderElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);

            var isValid = newBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val() == 'True';
            if (isValid) {
                //$('#notification').text('Data saved successfully!');
                //location.reload();
                //placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');

                var tableElement = $('#tblName');
                var tableUrl = tableElement.data('url');
                $.get(tableUrl).done(function (table) {
                    tableElement.replaceWith(table);
                });

            }
            else { 
            //    $('#notification').text('Data operation failed!');
                
                
                placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
                bootstrap.Alert();
            }
            
            bootstrap.Alert();
            placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
           
        });
    });
});
```

** CustomerMasterController.cs **

```
using IDESK.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IDESK.Models.Customer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using IDESK.Extensions.Alert;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using CsvHelper;


namespace IDESK.Controllers.Customer
{
    public class CustomerMasterController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DbConn _dbConn;
        public static List<Cust_Master> ItemList = new();
        public SelectList Customers { get; set; }
        
    public CustomerMasterController(DbConn _db)
        {
            _dbConn = _db;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                var ListItem = _dbConn.CUST_MAST.ToList(); //--for single table
                var isAjax = Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
                if (isAjax)
                {
                    return PartialView("_tblCustomer", ListItem);
                }
                // ModelState.Clear();
                return View(ListItem);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create(string action)
        {
            LoadDDL();
            LoadIncoTerms();
            LoadCurrency();
            LoadCustGrop();
            Cust_Master custmast = new Cust_Master();
            return PartialView("_Customer", custmast);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Cust_Master collection, string action)
        {
            int result = 0;
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (action == "Edit")
                    {
                        result = (int)(_dbConn.Entry(collection).State = EntityState.Modified);
                        await _dbConn.SaveChangesAsync();
                        ViewBag.action = "Edit";
                        TempData["Message"] = "Customer Master data Updated!";
                        TempData["Alert"] = CommonServices.CommonServices.ShowAlert(Alerts.Success, TempData["Message"].ToString());
                        return PartialView("_Customer", collection);
                    }
                    else if (action == "Create")
                    {
                            _dbConn.CUST_MAST.Add(collection);
                            result = (int)await _dbConn.SaveChangesAsync();
                            TempData["Message"] = "Customer Master data Created!";
                            ViewBag.action = "Create";
                            TempData["Alert"] = CommonServices.CommonServices.ShowAlert(Alerts.Success, TempData["Message"].ToString());
                        //ShowMsg();
                        LoadDDL();
                        LoadIncoTerms();
                        LoadCurrency();
                        LoadCustGrop();
                        return PartialView("_Customer", collection);

                            //return PartialView("Index", collection);
                        
                    }
                    else if (action == "Delete")
                    {
                        result = (int)(_dbConn.Entry(collection).State = EntityState.Deleted);
                        await _dbConn.SaveChangesAsync();
                        ViewBag.action = "Delete";
                        TempData["Message"] = "Customer Master data Deleted!";
                        TempData["Alert"] = CommonServices.CommonServices.ShowAlert(Alerts.secondary, TempData["Message"].ToString());
                    }
                    if (result <= 0)
                        TempData["Alert"] = CommonServices.CommonServices.ShowAlert(Alerts.Danger, "Unknown error : Operation failed");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "Operation failed! ...Invalid or Incomplete Data!";
                    TempData["Alert"] = CommonServices.CommonServices.ShowAlert(Alerts.Danger, TempData["Message"].ToString());
                    _dbConn.Entry(collection).State = EntityState.Detached;
                    // ShowMsg();
                    
                    return PartialView("_Customer", collection);
                   // return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    //return PartialView("_AlertMsg");
                }

                _dbConn.Entry(collection).State = EntityState.Detached; //---Clears current state.
                //return RedirectToAction("Index");
                return PartialView("_Customer", collection);
                //return PartialView("_tblPartial", collection);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Operation failed.\n" + ex.ToString();
                TempData["Alert"] = CommonServices.CommonServices.ShowAlert(Alerts.Danger, TempData["Message"].ToString());
                //ModelState.Clear();
                _dbConn.Entry(collection).State = EntityState.Detached; //---Clears current state.
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(Cust_Master collection)
        {
            ViewBag.action = "Edit";
            LoadDDL();
            LoadIncoTerms();
            LoadCurrency();
            LoadCustGrop();
            return PartialView("_Customer", collection);
        }
        public ActionResult ShowMsg()
        {
            return Content("Data added successfully");
        }
        public ActionResult Delete(Cust_Master collection)
        {
            ViewBag.action = "Delete";
            LoadDDL();
            LoadIncoTerms();
            LoadCurrency();
            LoadCustGrop();
            return PartialView("_Customer", collection);
        }

        private void LoadDDL() //--Load Dept dropdown list.
        {
            try
            {
                var custRegnList = _dbConn.CUST_REGION.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = String.Format("{0,-10} : {1} : {2} : {3} : {4} ", x.CUST_REGN, x.REGN_NAME,x.COUNTRY,x.STATE,x.CITY),
                    Value = x.CUST_REGN.ToString()
                }).ToList();

                ViewBag.CustRegnList = new SelectList(custRegnList, "Value", "Text");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void LoadIncoTerms() //--Load Dept dropdown list.
        {
            try
            {
                var IncoList = _dbConn.INCO_TERMS.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = String.Format("{0,-10} : {1}", x.INCO_TERMS, x.INCO_DESC),
                    Value = x.INCO_TERMS.ToString()
                }).ToList();

                ViewBag.IncoList = new SelectList(IncoList, "Value", "Text");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        private void LoadCurrency() //--Load Dept dropdown list.
        {
            try
            {
                var Currency = _dbConn.CURRENCY.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = String.Format("{0,-10} : {1}", x.BILL_CURCY, x.CURCY_NAME),
                    Value = x.BILL_CURCY.ToString()
                }).ToList();

                ViewBag.Currency = new SelectList(Currency, "Value", "Text");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void LoadCustGrop() 
        {
            try
            {
                var CustGroup = _dbConn.CUST_GROUP.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = String.Format("{0,-10} : {1}", x.CUST_GROUP, x.CUST_GRP_DTL),
                    Value = x.CUST_GROUP.ToString()
                }).ToList();

                ViewBag.CustGroup = new SelectList(CustGroup, "Value", "Text");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            this.Customers = new SelectList(this._dbConn.CUST_REGION, "CUST_REGN", "CUST_NAME");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used F12 to see any error in the console ? Could you share the controller's code? So that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sure. I am attaching the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

In Index view, call the partialview, and use modal form validation after using select2. You can refer to it.

HomeController:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new Cust_Master();
            var CustGroup = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value="a", Text ="aaaaaaa"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "b", Text = "b"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "c", Text = "c"},
             new SelectListItem {Value = "d", Text = "d"},
              new SelectListItem {Value = "e", Text = "e"},
        };
            ViewBag.CustGroup = CustGroup;
            return View(model);         
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Cust_Master cust_Master)
        {
            
            return View();
        }
```

Index view:

```
@model Cust_Master
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
@{
      Html.RenderPartial("_IndexPartial");   
  }
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnShowModal").click(function () {
              
            $("#Modal").modal('show'); 
            $("#btnHideModal").click(function () {
                $("#Modal").modal('hide');
            });
            });
            $("#e1").select2({
                    dropdownParent: $('#Modal')
                });
            $("#checkbox").click(function(){
                if($("#checkbox").is(':checked') ){
                    $("#e1 > option").prop("selected","selected");// Select All Options
                    $("#e1").trigger("change");// Trigger change to select 2
                }else{
                    $("#e1 > option").removeAttr("selected");
                    $("#e1").trigger("change");// Trigger change to select 2
                 }
            });

            $("#button").click(function(){
                   alert($("#e1").val());
            });
          });

    </script>}
```

Cust_Master:

```
 public class Cust_Master
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "CUST_CODE")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Customer Code")]
        public int CUST_CODE { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "CUST_NAME")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Customer Name")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string CUST_NAME { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "CUST_GROUP")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Customer Customer Group")]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public List<string> CUST_GROUP { get; set; }
    }
```

_IndexPartial:

```
@model Cust_Master
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_IndexPartial";
}
<h1>_IndexPartial</h1>
<hr />

<button id="btnShowModal" type="button" > Modal </button>
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" >                                            
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
 <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <button  id="btnHideModal" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">  ×</button>
      </div>                                                             
    <div class="modal-body" >  
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Index"  >
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CUST_CODE" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CUST_CODE" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CUST_CODE" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CUST_NAME" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CUST_NAME" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CUST_NAME" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
         
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CUST_GROUP" class="control-label"></label>
                 <select multiple  asp-for="CUST_GROUP" class="form-control select2-results  col-md-6" id="e1"  style="width:300px" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.CustGroup, "Value", "Text"))">
               @*  <option value="">---Select Customer Group---</option>*@
                 </select>
            
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All

               <input type="button" id="button" value="check Selected">
                <span asp-validation-for="CUST_GROUP" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank Qing, I will test and reverback to you.

Comment: You are not calling seperate model partialView, in my case it is _Create.cshtml which may be called any where.

Comment: This is not working for me.

Comment: OK, I will try to  call  seperate model partialView and please see my later update answer.

Comment: "But when press submit button, required fields as per model are not validating"Have you see any error in the console after using `F12`?

Comment: Yes, my console having some error:

Comment: Yes, my console having some error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, String dataValueField, String dataTextField, IEnumerable selectedValues, String dataGroupField)

Comment: Right now the said problem get resolved. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/895311/bootstrap-modal-form-validation-with-slect2.html#answer-form

Answer (score 0):

Behind all these scenaraios, I have changed my button type 'button' to input type 'submit' then validation worked fine.

But after that another proble produced. From controller,

**return PartialView("_Customer", collection);**
caused existing layout null.